# Jquery datatable alignment issue - Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have datatable in popup window(dialog).This datatable values getting from search button.So each button click the table getting lesser width in firefox, but IE working good. Please advise how to fix this issue ? I'm controlling the datatable width through  below code.

```
<div id="table_container" style="width : 630px">
```

[image]

Comment: Can you point out which part gets lesser?

Comment: Right side of table, the column header should be equal to table header.

Comment: "**but IE working good**".  first time I hear.

Comment: Ｉn my FF, it works well, don't find issue in fiddle site. My ff version is 22.